# Changing citation style using biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have two problems regarding the citation style, see example.

1. At first, the citation should be without the title of the work for
   space sparing reasons.
2. Second, the `volume.number (Month Year)` notation should be replaced
   by a `\bf{volume}, number (year)` notation.

Here is the LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[open=right,titlepage=on,headsepline=on,numbers=enddot,ngerman,12pt,draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=authortitle,labelyear=true,backend=biber,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{mini}
\begin{document}
\footcite{sigmund_mechanism_1973}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and this is the `mini.bib` file:

```
@article{sigmund_mechanism_1973,
    title = {A mechanism of surface micro-roughening by ion bombardment},
    volume = {8},
    issn = {0022-2461, 1573-4803},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00754888},
    doi = {10.1007/BF00754888},
    abstract = {},
    language = {en},
    number = {11},
    urldate = {2014-02-24},
    journal = {J Mater Sci},
    author = {Sigmund, Peter},
    month = nov,
    year = {1973},
    keywords = {Characterization and Evaluation Materials, Industrial {Chemistry/Chemical} Engineering, Mechanics, Polymer Sciences},
    pages = {1545--1553},
    file = {}
},
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @user49013: Please reduce your latex code to a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Are you sure it is the `verbose-ibid` citation style you want? One point of the "verbose" styles is that they can be used without a list of references, since everything is there (in the first citation, at least), which is a reason why they won't omit the title.

With `style=authortitle-terse` you have a predefined style that only prints the author name (providing there is just one title by that author, of course).

Comment: `style=authortitle-terse` gives in my case only the name. What want is in the footnote `autor, journal, \bf{vol}, number (year)` and in the bibligrapy `autor, title, journal, \bf{vol}, number (year)`.

Comment: @strpeter: Done. Hopefully this helps for answering the question.

Comment: @user49013: You could further reduce your MWE by dropping `babel` and some options of the documentclass (+1 for good question). But I am not an expert concerning your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is not very specific on how to cite works other than `@article`s (`@book`s, `@incollection`s etc. pp).

Answer (score 4):

You could try these modifications to `verbose-ibid`

We use a comma for punctuation

```
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

The `language` list will not be displayed, we also drop the `title` in citations.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{language}\clearfield{title}}
```

The volume is printed in bold

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```

No "In:" ...

```
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
```

There is a comma between volume and number in `@articles`

```
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

There is no such thing as a short citation here, so we always either print the full thing or just ibid.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifciteibid}
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=authortitle,labelyear=true,backend=biber,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigmund_mechanism_1973,
    title = {A mechanism of surface micro-roughening by ion bombardment},
shorttitle = {hi},
    volume = {8},
    issn = {0022-2461, 1573-4803},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00754888},
    doi = {10.1007/BF00754888},
    language = {en},
    number = {11},
    urldate = {2014-02-24},
    journal = {J Mater Sci},
    author = {Sigmund, Peter},
    month = nov,
    year = {1973},
    keywords = {Characterization and Evaluation Materials, Industrial {Chemistry/Chemical} Engineering, Mechanics, Polymer Sciences},
    pages = {1545--1553},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{language}\clearfield{title}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifciteibid}
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum\footcite{sigmund_mechanism_1973}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]